# counter parameter in Java

Tags: java

I need to write method, called clearStacks() and another one, called pickUpStack() as follows:

- pickUpStack() should pick up one stack of beepers, count it and print out its size. It
  should count the beepers and print out how many there were in the stack.
- clearStacks() should clear a row of beepers. It should call pickUpStack() to do the work of picking up one stack.

My code includes the overall number of beepers, however I need to write how many beepers picked up from each stack.

```
int pickUpStack()
{
    int numBeeper=0;
    while(isItemOnGroundAtRobot())
    {
        pickUpItemWithRobot();
        ++numBeeper;
    }
    return numBeeper;
}

void moveRobotToNextStack()
{
    while(!isItemOnGroundAtRobot()&&!isRobotFacingWall())
        moveRobotForwards();
}

void clearStacks()
{    
    int numBeeper=0;
    numBeeper=pickUpStack();
    while(!isRobotFacingWall())
    {
        moveRobotToNextStack();
        numBeeper+=pickUpStack();
    }
    println("Beepers: "+numBeeper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could keep a count of the number of beepers picked up from each stack.  Which one you choose really depends on your requirements.

Print it from your `pickUpStack()` method:

```
int pickUpStack()
{
    int numBeeper=0;
    while(isItemOnGroundAtRobot())
    {
        pickUpItemWithRobot();
        ++numBeeper;
    }
    println("Beepers from current stack" + numBeeper);
    return numBeeper;
}
```

Or keep a `List` of return values

```
void clearStacks()
{    
    List beeperList = new ArrayList();
    int numBeeper=0;
    numBeeper=pickUpStack();
    while(!isRobotFacingWall())
    {
        moveRobotToNextStack();
        int currentBeepers = pickUpStack();
        beeperList.add(currentBeepers);

        numBeeper+=currentBeepers ;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< beeperList.size(); i++)
        println("Stack " + i + " contains " + beeperList.get(i) + " beepers");

    println("Total beepers: "+numBeeper);
}
```